# How Can I update node of one yaml file from content of another yaml file?

Tags: yaml, yq

I have two yaml files:

```
key: value
configmap:
  data:
    foo: bar
```

```
app: test
config:
  testKey: testValue
```

I want to update file1.yaml's `configmap.data` with file2.yaml's `config` and save it back in `file1.yaml` so file1.yaml becomes:

```
key: value
configmap:
 data:
  testKey: testValue
```

How can I do this?

I tried the yq command

`yq -i e '(select(fileIndex==0).configmap.data = select(fileIndex==1).config)' 'file1.yaml' 'file2.yaml'`

But I got the following output, which appended the content of file1.yaml instead of updating it

```
key: value
configmap:
  data:
    foo: bar
---
app: test
config:
  testKey: testValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (as opposed to [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) which goes by the same name and can also [be referenced by the `yq` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info), but using it would require a very different solution of this problem).

You can use the `load` function to load the contents of another file, then just assign the values of and to the right fields:

```bash
yq '.configmap.data = load("file2.yaml").config' file1.yaml
```

```yaml
key: value
configmap:
  data:
    testKey: testValue
```

Add the `-i` flag to save the changes back into the primary input file (file1.yaml).

Tested with mikefarah/yq version v4.34.2. (Note that since version 4.18.1, the `eval`/`e` command is the default command, and no longer needs to be specified.)

---

If you needed to specify the file names on shell level, e.g. from variables (which is trivial if they are plain arguments, but not so much if they have become part of the filter code), be aware that injecting them into the code string isn't good practice and creates unnecessary vulnerabilities. Instead, set environment variables, and use the `strenv` function to read them:

```bash
src=file2.yaml yq '.configmap.data = load(strenv(src)).config' file1.yaml
```

However, if you're for some reason restricted to provide all files as parameters, your approach of using `fileIndex`/`file_index`/`fi` is indeed the way to go. Use the `eval-all`/`ea` command to gather all sources into the same main context, and either reduce eventually to the target file's sub-context by appending another `select` filter (closest to your approach), or reduce before the assignment (break `select(fi==0).xxx =` into `select(fi==0) | .xxx =`) yet after presetting a variable to carry over a value from another sub-context:

```bash
yq ea 'select(fi==0).configmap.data = select(fi==1).config | select(fi==0)' file1.yaml file2.yaml
# or
yq ea 'select(fi==1).config as $cfg | select(fi==0) | .configmap.data = $cfg' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```